# Acoustic Echo Cancellation (AEC) with Speex and DirectSound

Tags: c++, audio, echo, directsound, speex

I am trying to perform Acoustic Echo Cancellation (AEC) with the Speex codec library. According to the Speex documentation, I need to perform two calls:

```
 speex_echo_playback(echo_state, echo_frame);
```

every time an audio frame is played, and

```
 speex_echo_capture(echo_state, input_frame, output_frame);
```

for every frame captured.

Since I am using DirectSound, I was thinking that I could use the primary DirectSound buffer as the echo_frame in the call to speex_echo_playback, e.g.,

```
  DWORD offset = 0;
  DWORD length = 0;
  LPVOID block1, block2;
  DWORD length1, length2;
  DWORD flags = DSBLOCK_ENTIREBUFFER;

  HRESULT hr = primary_buffer->Lock(
        offset
      , length
      , &block1
      , &length1
      , &block2
      , &length2
      , flags
      );

  // Would like to convert the buffer into a form that
  // speex_echo_capture() can use.
  // Why does length1 == length2 == 0 always? 

  hr = primary_buffer->Unlock( block1, length1, block2, length2 );
```

The documentation does say that these are write-only pointers, but is there not anyway to use the buffer data myself?

This is basically how I am creating the buffer:

```
  CComPtr< IDirectSoundBuffer > primary_buffer;
  DSBUFFERDESC primarydesc = { sizeof( DSBUFFERDESC ),
      DSBCAPS_PRIMARYBUFFER | DSBCAPS_CTRL3D | DSBCAPS_LOCHARDWARE,
      0, 0, NULL, DS3DALG_HRTF_LIGHT };
  HRESULT hr = directsound_->CreateSoundBuffer(
      &primarydesc, &primary_buffer, NULL );
```

The alternative, it seems, to using the DirectSound buffer itself is to use the output of speex_decode() and do my own software mixing.

Any pointers or suggestions for getting Speex and DirectSound to work together? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why are you using the low level API of DirectSound? you can write an effect DMO which a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. Do you have a basic usage example of a DirectX Media Object (DMO)? I am working on top of a fair amount of code infrastructure, so I'm not sure how easy I can use a DMO.

Comment: > Why are you using the low level API of DirectSound?


- Because it allows to write portable code.

Answer (score 3):

I've done this once. But my approach was the following:

I've never used Primary buffer directly. Instead, I worked only with one secondary buffer. I had two threads - playback thread and capture thread. Also, I've used another speex function -  [speex_echo_cancellation](http://www.speex.org/docs/api/speex-api-reference/group__SpeexEchoState.html#g306c6fd37bb64e4de6a50808e65cbedf).

Thus, in my playback thread I've saved current playback frame in a global buffer and in capture thread called speex_echo_cancellation function with currect capture frame and previously stored playback frame.

DMO was not applicable for me because I had to support Windows XP also.

You can also look throug  - [speex mailing lists archive](http://lists.xiph.org/pipermail/speex-dev/) or better even [subscribe here](http://lists.xiph.org/mailman/listinfo/speex-dev) to get more interesting info.

Good luck,

Anthony